# Why do we need the Option type when we have code contracts/static analysis?

Tags: scala, f#, null, static-analysis, code-contracts

When designing a null safe piece of code, what's the better approach?

F# and Scala has Options type that encapsulates null check, but we also have static code analysis tools like code contracts, findbugs.

To me static analysis seems a little cleaner, so what is the reason for Option/Maybe? In particular, what makes it better in preventing NullPointerExceptions/NullReferenceExceptions?

Comment: Well, first off, what *is* the Option type? How can it be used with pattern matching and `for`? (Option isn't about "finding bugs", it's about *correctly* modeling a problem in a consistent manner; null is [an unfortunate side-effect of ALGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) and an unfortunate aspect borrowed by Java/JVM and thus Scala.)

Comment: I don't think it's a "bad" question, but I think it sets up an improper duality. Using Option/Maybe doesn't exclude the other tooling; just as neither exclude tests.

Comment: @pst *null* is also a very efficient way to declare a pointer type invalid in about any language which allows to get this close to the hardware layer (Assembler, C, C++, and probably lots more). It would be very nice if also every primitive numeric type had a null value, like *Double.NAN*.

Comment: @ziggystar I disagree. How "null" is handled internally to a language that *did not expose it* (i.e the language *only* has Maybe to represent "something or nothing" like Haskell) is an implementation detail. For instance, Java implementations use *pointers*, but there are no pointers in Java! There is no reason why it must be "less efficient". Also, case C# shows, it's possible to create a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type over primitives with minimal overhead: but a .NET Nullable type *doesn't unify like Option/Maybe*.

Comment: @ziggystar At this point, every "modern high-level language" that has null is just result of not fixing this fundamental thinking about the issue. It's how ALGO worked. It's how C works. It's how Java works. It's how C# works. It *doesn't* mean it's the best way; it just means it has been perpetuated.

Comment: @ziggystar Also, why the entire null thing can be eliminated in a *new* statically typed language, there is no need for the same idea of null as propagated C/Java/C#. Some dynamically typed languages like Objective-C have `nil` which will accept all messages passed to it (like a giant garbage disposal). Other languages like Ruby have `nil` which is *itself an object* (it is the only inhabitant of the NilClass type) and can respond to messages like any other object.

Comment: @pst I agree that the safety and expressiveness `Option` provides is great. But as long as it comes with a performance overhead, as it is the case with current Scala(2.10), I **cannot** avoid using null in some cases. And while Haskell is a very nice language, writing fast code is extremely difficult. I agree that both problems (performance and safety) can be solved at once, and maybe this will soon happen in Scala. But it's 2010, and C, C++, ALGOL are rather old languages, no?

Comment: @ziggystar Again, if Option/Maybe was supported at the language-level as a *complete replacement* of "null" and *promoted as such in the implementation* then there would be no performance issue for valid code. It would be an implementation detail of using "null" under the covers: this "performance" issue does not need to exist. Neither Scala nor F# do this; however, they must *unfortunately* pamper to the respective VMs and interoperability issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Option` is used to model the fact that computation *maybe* return a value. It doesn't exist merely to encapsulate null check; many functional programming languages such as SML, Haskell don't have `null` but `Option/Maybe` are present as useful tools for modeling problems.

> To me static analysis seems a little cleaner, so what is the reason for Option/Maybe?

In the context of functional programming, using static analysis to check the absence of values is *overkill*. Static type checking can do it just fine (with `Option`). And the type systems can guarantee absolute correctness while static analysis tools may have false positives.

Another problem with static analysis tools is *high cost*. It costs a lot to build them (I don't know any good static analysis tools for F# and Scala) and to use them (software purchase, developer training). Admittedly, they are powerful and should be used to catch more subtle errors (which can't be caught by static type checkers) such as index out of bounds, integer overflows, etc.

Comment: +1 Although with "Not Null" attributes rolling out and other such "code contracts", much more information than just the method name and parameters can be exposed/encoded (even if not part of the types themselves) .. Scala tools just suck in comparison to Visual Studio (+ Extensions) for languages like C#. That's all there is to that :(

Answer (score 11):

`Option` is monadic. A primary benefit is transparent integration into monadic chains of computation, typically using the `for` comprehension syntax.

Furthermore, I doubt static analysis could even in principle obviate tests for the presence or absence of a value (the `Some` / `None` distinction). Offhand my intuition is that it would be the equivalent of the halting problem.

Comment: Various not-null analysis can detect provably-not-null vs. maybe-null and prevent the latter (unless it is turned into a provably-not-null value) - in this case neither can do more (or less). One just requires a Some match (or map or whatnot) while the other requires an `if (x != null) { use(x) }` .. now, if Scala *prohibited* the use of `null` for an Option type and *prohibited* creating Some(null), then .. but both approaches run into "boundary" issues, just in different ways.

Comment: That being said, +1 for the first paragraph - until one *uses* Option/Maybe for what it is (instead of a simple "null-guard"), one can't truly enjoy the existence of the Option/Maybe types.

Answer (score 9):

For one thing, static analysis can only work if the API is annotated or full source/bytecode is available.

If you have an API but the actual library implementing it will be decided at runtime, static analysis is helpless.

For another thing, static analysis is intrinsically limited. The limitations of turing completeness apply, which means it can't decide whether something maybe be null or not in all cases.

So, these are all limitations of static analysis, not shared by option types, but option types have an additional advantage: they are monads. That means you can compose computation with them, while you'd have to resort to repeating yourself if limited to if-checks for nullability.

The last statement is probably unclear, but it's the nature of the thing: if you understand how monads are used, you don't need further explanation; if you do not, then explanations won't help you much. The best way to learn the usage of monads is to use it -- same as everything else in programming, really.